# Pagination doesn't work in query post in tag template

Tags: query-posts, navigation, template-tags

In tag template I use the following query post:

```
                global $query_string; // required
                $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                $posts =                    query_posts($query_string.'&posts_per_page=5&cat=-93&paged=' . $paged);  

                if ( have_posts() ) :

                    /* Start the Loop */
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                (content)
                endwhile;
                endif;
                wp_reset_query(); // reset the query 

                the_posts_pagination( array( 'prev_text' => 'prev', 'next_text' => 'next' ) );
```

This is to have the post from current tag but exclude one category and show 5 post per page.
But this query post the navigation doesn't work.

I added also the string for 'paged' but nothing changes.

Comment: search this site for `pre_get_posts`. you should alter the main query, not create a new query in the template.

Comment: what means alter main query? I found pre_get_posts in some solutions of this problem but I don't understand how implement it... Can you help me? @Milo

Comment: Is there someone that can help me?

Comment: I solved.. there was a problem with another plugin..